# Understanding Demeter's Law

Tags: oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, law-of-demeter

I'm trying to understand the SOLID principles behind OOP and came across with this doubt.

[image: Class Diagram]

Following the previous class diagram, I am going to calculate the base_cost for a Vehicle. For such, I need to access the horsepower and the tax and then calculate everything with the base_cost() function.

[image: Pseudocode]

From what I understood in this [link](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3136224/demystifying-the-law-of-demeter-principle.html#:%7E:text=The%20Law%20of%20Demeter%20principle%20states%20that%20a%20module%20should,of%20other%20objects%20or%20components.) I could guess that it DOES NOT violate Demeter's law since you are accessing methods from a class created locally (Vehicle). Am I right?

Comment: The D in SOLID does not stand for Demeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, SOLID does *not* include the Law of Demeter. Which is a shame, because [it is much more pertinent and useful than all of the SOLID suggestions](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/05/14/the-genius-of-the-law-of-demeter/). Just to get that out of the way.

Regarding your exact case, calling methods on the `vehicle` is of course allowed by Demeter, because that object is held as an instance variable. There is an explicit rule for that.

*However*, if we're thinking about an object-oriented system, things returned by `get_price()`, `get_power()` and `get_tax()` are *also objects*, since everything is supposed to be an object in an OO system. In Law of Demeter context, multiplying the returned values *is* "sending messages" to those objects. Now this is **not allowed**, since you don't directly hold references to *those* objects nor are they parameters nor created in this call.

So, while "getting" objects/values might be technically legal according to the Law of Demeter, calling methods on *those* objects/values that you got are not. So basically anything that has "getters" *will* eventually violate the Law of Demeter.

This is on purpose. What the Law of Demeter actually enforces is *encapsulation*. The idea that you don't want to "get" data out of an object, instead you want to ask the object to perform behavior using the data it has.